# Is possible to build modules on demand?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I want to build angular app modules on demand, in that way I can build some modules for app A as required, and build other modules for app B, app A and B have some common modules, also some different modules due to different business functions. All the modules are in the same angular project.

This is for a configurable front-end product base on angular that we can decide which module need to be build and which does not through a configuration file.
I'm now trying to do this using webpack, not angular-cli, I believe if webpack.config.js works, so does angular-cli.

My angular project is build on [ng-alain](https://ng-alain.com/docs/getting-started/en), and the project structure is as follows:

```
--src
  |_app
    |_routes
      |_callback
      |_dashboard
      |_test1
        |_test1.module.ts
        |_test1-routing.module.ts
      |_test2
        |_test2.module.ts
        |_test2-routing.module.ts
      |_test3
        |_test3.module.ts
        |_test3-routing.module.ts
      |_test4
        |_test4.module.ts
        |_test4-routing.module.ts
      |_routes.module.ts
      |_routes-routing.module.ts
```

the parent module is:

```
|_routes
  |_routes.module.ts
  |_routes-routing.module.ts
```

the common modules are:

```
|_routes
    |_callback
    |_dashboard
    |_test1
      |_test1.module.ts
      |_test1-routing.module.ts
    |_test2
      |_test2.module.ts
      |_test2-routing.module.ts
```

if app A require the common modules and test1、test2、test3, so I need to build app A with the following modules:

```
|_routes
    |_callback
    |_dashboard
    |_test1
      |_test1.module.ts
      |_test1-routing.module.ts
    |_test2
      |_test2.module.ts
      |_test2-routing.module.ts
    |_test3
      |_test3.module.ts
      |_test3-routing.module.ts
```

and app B require the common modules and test1、test2、test4, so I need to build app B with the following modules:

```
|_routes
    |_callback
    |_dashboard
    |_test1
      |_test1.module.ts
      |_test1-routing.module.ts
    |_test2
      |_test2.module.ts
      |_test2-routing.module.ts
    |_test4
      |_test4.module.ts
      |_test4-routing.module.ts
```

I looked up some information about this, and I found [micro app](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/05/04/microservice-clients-with-web-components-using-angular-elements-dreams-of-the-near-future.aspx),I don't think it is a solution for me, it's complicated for a simple app.
Is there any plugins in webpack or some other way can help me to do this?

Comment: Q: If you want to build modules "on the fly" ...then what's wrong with simply writing a WebPack config file "on the fly"?

Comment: I can not find which plugin in webpack can help me.

Comment: Maybe something like `Nx` (https://nx.dev/) a monorepo?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it